# Iterate a list without next()

Tags: python, loops, iteration, pyscript

I have a list called current_month_list which is populated each month with Mondays in the month. ie for June it would be:

```
current_month_list = 6, 13, 20, 27
```

Im using

```
next_rubbish_day = next(x for x in current_month_list if x > todays_date.day)
```

to return the next Monday in the list i.e. 20 as todays the 16

This has worked well but im trying to convert over to Pyscript it use this in a different environment and apparently (quoted on another site) '

> pyscript includes an async python interpreter and doesn't implement
> certain features that are particularly difficult in an interpreter.
> That includes generators.

The error im getting is

> not implemented ast ast_generatorexp

So my question is, is there another way to code this. Im not to good with python so would appreciate some help. Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: Just use a regular for-loop. If you came up with the above, then that should be straight-forward

Comment: Does it implement the builtin `filter`? `next_rubbish_day = next(filter(lambda x : x > todays_data.day, current_month_list))`?

Comment: Your current function will raise a `StopIteration` exception when today's date is after the last Monday. What's the expected behavior for that case?

Answer (score 0):

Since generators are forbidden, just fall back to a regular loop. `next()` will return the next item in that generator expression, and since you just created the generator, that will be the first item. So just break out of your loop once you have your first item:

```
for x in current_month_list:
    if x > todays_date.day: 
        next_rubbish_day = x
        break
```

Now, this code will not throw any errors if none of `x > todays_date.day` in `current_month_list`; your original code would throw a `StopIteration` exception. To implement this functionality, all you need is to use the [`for..else` form](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html#for-else):

```
for x in current_month_list:
    if x > todays_date.day: 
        next_rubbish_day = x
        break 
else:
    # This code runs only if the loop finishes without being broken
    raise StopIteration()
```

This snippet behaves identically as far as I know to your `next(...)` statement.

Comment: That will give us some to work with. Thanks.

Comment: @user12155673 note that as you have shown it in your question, `current_month_list` is actually a tuple, but that is irrelevant in this situation since all you do with that tuple is iterate over it, so it could be any iterable. Also, as @Mark has pointed out, if there is no element that satisfies your criteria, your original code will throw a `StopIterationError`. You can implement this by using a `for...else` construct as I will shortly edit my answer to demonstrate

Answer (score 0):

Probably do something like this (you'll have to set or import the `todays_date.day`).  There are bunch of ways to do this with for, while, break, return, etc.  Really just depends on what you want!  Good luck!

```
def main():
    print(date_fun())
    
def date_fun():    
    current_month_list = [6, 13, 20, 27]
    for y in current_month_list:
        if y > todays_date.day:
            return y

main()
```